# requirements for home firewall setup

Tags: networking, firewall

I have a bunch of machines I want to access from internet (via DDNS), but for security want to separate them from the rest of my machines at home.

Q1) Am I right in saying that I need a firewall with at least 3 network segments - one for internet, one for DMZ, and one for the rest of my stuff?

Q2) Should the setup should be:

```
             /--> DMZ
Internet -> FW
             \--> Internal
```

Q3) Whats would be the minimum set of requirements for hardware FW that would do the job above?

Comment: Q3) is off-topic since we don't do shopping/product recommendations here.

Comment: @Karan edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I you only need a few ports open on those machines, you could just use PAT (Port Address Translation), sometimes called NAT in router configuration. That is really enough for home use, I think. You can map your public port to local machines local port and thus public domain will be able to access them.

Yeah, another possibility is to implement the scheme @Q2. This would be a little more secure.

Comment: I guess the issue is that if I enable remote desktop to those machines, someone could guess my password and then get inside my network. Would be better to have them inside an isolated DMZ I think.

Comment: I wouldn't consider opening the management port like RD to the public secure at all either. Try to go with VPN. Does your router support that? There are a lot of cheaper ones even that support at least pass-through VPNs